# Why does wrapping a list() around a map cause functions to run?

Tags: python, multithreading

The problem I am trying to solve is to map across a list of functions in a multithreaded manor. These functions both print something out and have a return value. Each of these return values will be stored in a list. Here is the code...

```
 import threading
 import time

 def PauseAndPrint1Seconds(num):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Finished Pausing" + num)
    return [1]

 def PauseAndPrint2Seconds(num):
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Finished Pausing" + num)
    return [2, 2]

 def PauseAndPrint3Seconds(num):
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Finished Pausing" + num)
    return [3, 3, 3]

 def PauseAndPrint4Seconds(num):
    time.sleep(4)
    print("Finished Pausing" + num)
    return [4, 4, 4, 4]


 myfuncs = [PauseAndPrint1Seconds, PauseAndPrint2Seconds, PauseAndPrint3Seconds, PauseAndPrint4Seconds]

 result = [None] * len(myfuncs)

 def wrapFunc(i, num):
    result[i] = myfuncs[i](num)

 mythreads = [threading.Thread(target=wrapFunc, args = (i, " 12345")) for i in range(len(myfuncs))]

 map(lambda x: x.start(), mythreads)

 map(lambda x: x.join(), mythreads)
```

The threads were never started and I get this back...

```
 >>> map(lambda x: x.start(), mythreads)
 <map object at 0x7fd1a551b3c8>


 >>> result
 [None, None, None, None]
```

If I change the map function to simple loops it seems to work

```
>>> for x in mythreads:
...     x.start()

Finished Pausing 12345
Finished Pausing 12345
Finished Pausing 12345
Finished Pausing 12345

>>> result
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Also curiously the exact map function that doesn't work indeed does if I wrap the map with a list() call.

```
 >>> list(map(lambda x: x.start(), mythreads))
 [None, None, None, None]
 Finished Pausing 12345
 Finished Pausing 12345
 Finished Pausing 12345
 Finished Pausing 12345

 >>> result
 [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Couple of wrap up things...
1. I am new to Python so sorry if I missed something basic
2. I know there is an easier way to do this. It is a question for my understanding.

Comment: Maps are lazy - they only produce each element when required to. By calling `list(your_map)`, you force the map to produce all the elements right away to put into the list, which means calling the mapped function on each element of `mythreads`. If you want to achieve "map-like" results eagerly, consider using a list comprehension instead: `[x.start() for x in mythreads]` and so forth.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, `map()` function doesn't return a `list` but a `iterator`.

Comment: Let the standard library do the work for you. The `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` class manages the threads and has a `map` method that spreads the processing out among threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a difference between Python2 and Python3.

Python3 returns a map object which remembers what needs to be done (like a generator), but doesn't do any work until you ask for the results (creating a list from the results of the map object is asking for them all at once)

`map`in Python2 already returns a list, so is similar to `list(map(...))` in Python3

It's generally not considered Pythonic to use map or list comprehensions just for their side effects. If you just used a `for` loop, there is no ambiguity about when things are happening

```
for x in mythreads:
    x.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

map function return generator. it means, it call the function when you try to get the result, as you do: `list(map(..))`.